# Can I use time as a predictor variable in a panel regression?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, multiple-regression, panel-data

Is it possible to generate a new variable "phase" that is based on the time the participants were questioned? I generated this new variable by dividing the time into three phases (beginning, middle, end) and would like to use it as an independent variable in a panel regression.
If I would use the time itself as an independent variable, this would logically result in an error, but I would like to see if the time has an effect on the dependent variable. How can I do this in a panel regression?

I generated the variable "phase" like this:

```
data <- data %>%
   mutate(phase = ifelse(session <= 13, 1,
                        ifelse(session <= 26, 2,
                             ifelse(session > 26,3, NA))))
```

My survey looks like this:

[image: The data looks like this]

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question. Maybe you can introduce equations to make the question more explicit. In particular, I do not understand " If I would use the time itself as an independent variable, this would logically result in an error."

Comment: I am very new to this. I hope it makes sense... 

diff = sex ∙ β1 + class ∙ β2 + grade ∙ β3 + phase ∙ β4 + β0 + u

(The pdata.frame function is then called internally, which returns a pdata.frame which is a data.frame with an attribute called index. This attribute is a data.frame that contains the individual and the time indexes.)

According to the quote, I assume I can not use the time index as an additional independent variable.

Comment: I generated a new variable (phase) which consists of the time, which I divided into three phases (beginning, middle, end). In this case I don't receive an error message, but I am afraid I actually can not use a variable that correlates with the time index used by the regression model.

Comment: Are you working in R? Which model do you use?

Comment: Yes, I am working with R. I use the plm package and would like to do a panel regression (random effects).

Comment: Hi Lisa. Do you have a panel of *individuals* surveyed across *years*? Also, now that R isn’t returning any error messages, are you most concerned with including other covariates, or do you want to know how to include “time” explicitly in your model specification?

Comment: Hey Tom, I have a panel of individuals surveyed across sessions. I do want to include time-invariant variables (sex, class, grade) and the variable "session" which is the time-variable. ( I generated a new variable by dividing the "sessions" into three phases (beginning, middle, end) "phase").

Comment: I added the way I generated the time-variable above in the description, as well as a picture of how my survey looks like. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: The visual helps! Based upon what I am seeing, I don't think you have panel data. Do you observe the *same person* across all three sessions? For example, the person with 'ID' - md10 should be observed multiple times in your panel. I tried to look for some other ordering scheme but I couldn't see it. Please elaborate further if possible!

Comment: @Tom : fd3 is observed in two sessions, fd9 and md9 as well. LisaMarie, have you shown all your data, or is this just a sample of your survey ?

Comment: Alex, yes good catch! Lisa, it is also good practice to organize your dataset by your panel identifier. For example, you could use `%>% arrange(ID)` after your `mutate(...)`. I will facilitate easy readability.

Comment: Right, it's just a sample. I observed each person 40 times. I figured I'll do a FE regression for my time variable and a RE regression for all other time-invariant variables. The coefficient for the time variable will indirectly be affected by the omitted variables... I just hope that it's reasonable... Thanks for your help!